# Laravel 6.x manipulate relationship data as attribute

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible in laravel to make own attributes with relationships?

For example:
Customer has a relationship with CustomerAddress. Now I want to fetch all Customers with relationsships and then have the attribute `address` on customer. The `address` field would be generated with multiple columns of the `customer_address` table.

The `customer_address` table has the columns `street`,`state` and they should connect to `address` on the customer model.

```php
$customer = \App\Customer::with("customerAddress")->get();
return $customer->address;
>> street.state
```

would that be possible, that toArray() and toJSON() not ignoring these custom attributes?

Comment: \App\Customer::with("customerAddress")->get() <<< this will get you a list of customers, not just one customer.

Comment: @MohammedRadwan thats not my problem. I want to fetch custom attributes in the collection via the model. And then only call `toJSON()` and the custom attribute should be a addition of 2 values of the relationship

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct relationship inside your models then define a method that returns the custom attribute and then add it to the `$appends` array

`Customer`

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['custom_attribute'];

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CustomerAddress::class, 'customer_id');
    }

    public function getCustomAttribute() {
        return 'some calculated data';
    }
}
```

`CustomerAddress`

```
class CustomerAddress extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['custom_attribute'];

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
    }

    public function getCustomAttribute() {
        return 'some calculated data';
    }
}
```

Note that the attribute name is sneak_case, while the method name is in StudlyCase prefixed with `get` (which makes it camelCase eventually). Method name and accessor name must match.

Now in your controller you can get all customers and their addresses.

```
$customers = Customer::with("addresses:street,state")->get();
```

If you access `$customers` you'll see all customers and their addresses. Now you can use the custom attribute to return custom values.

Example:

```
public function getCustomAttribute() {
      return "{$this->street} {$this->state}";
}
```

Comment: Thx, the only thing I need to know is how to access the relation from there.

Comment: I'm confused now :)

What exactly you want to do? Edit your question and be more specific and clear. First you said I need a custom attribute, which what I explained, and now you say you need to access the relation from there. Where is there?

Share your models code and DB structure and the relationship type (one to one, one to many, or many to many)

Comment: I want that `customer` becomes the attribute `address`. The `address` attribute should be generated with data from the relationship of `customer_address`. Is it possible that I can access this address with: `$customer->address` and then get a calculated data from `customer_address`. `customer_address` has for example `street` and `state`. Is it now for you clear? :D

Comment: What is the relationship type between customer and address? Is it one address per customer or multiple addresses per customer?

Comment: One customer can have multiple addresses